# How to import "loader" format data using SQLDeveloper?

Tags: import, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

How do I import data in "loader" format using SQL Developer?

SQLDeveloper can export data in "loader" format, so I would like to re-import it.

Note: I'm not able to login to the server on which the Oracle DB is running, and I don't have sysdba privileges.

Comment: The OracleClient_11gR2_W64.zip package locally installs binaries like sqlplus and sqlldr. I'll try to convince them to connect to the remote DB...

Comment: Agree to anyone who thinks this is a noob question. But took me more than an hour to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Install** OracleClient_11gR2_W64.zip package

Oracle home e.g. C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1

- Oracle Database Utilities
- SQL*Plus
- Oracle Call Interface (OCI)
- *Oracle Net (don't know if necessary)*

Edit the C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora, add a configuration for your remote DB, e.g. named ACME.

```
sqlldr  scott/tiger@ACME  control=BATCH_REPORTS_DATA_TABLE.ctl log=BATCH_REPORTS_DATA_TABLE.ctl.log
```

Also read this: **[How to install Oracle 11gR2 64-bit client on Windows 7](http://www.dadbm.com/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-64-bit-client-on-windows-7/)**

**Download** Oracle client 11gR2

- 64-bit: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html

  - [win64_11gR2_client.zip](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/112010/win64_11gR2_client.zip)  Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64) 615MB
- 32-bit:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

  - [win32_11gR2_client.zip](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/112010/win64_11gR2_client.zip) Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) 684MB

Comment: Well, this answer is not very satisfying, because the question explicitly asked about SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Agree with @Tom.  I don't have the `sqlldr` command installed on my dev workstation, so there's no way it'll be on my customer's computer should I need it.

Comment: I want to import .ldr files. It's true that this way is not with SQLDeveloper, but it was useful for me and worked perfectly. So thanks.